# Accidentally allowed threat in Windows Defender, how do I revoke access?

Tags: windows, windows-defender, exceptions

I'm posting this as a "question" here in the hopes that the 485 people who said "I have the same question" on a locked thread on the MS forums eventually find it and see the answer I just came across, because nowhere else on the internet seems to have documented this.

When you allow a threat through Windows Defender, the **Protection History** tab says "This app has been allowed and will not be remediated in the future". This is obviously concerning, especially because that tab does not show options to disallow that threat.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to basically poor design, as the option DOES exist in another spot.

Go to **Virus and Threat Protection** (the first tab of Defender), and click "Allowed Threats" under the quick scan button. Here you can remove exceptions that may have been accidents or one-offs. Hope this helps those who need it.